# App on app store logging suspicious in-app purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an app on Apple and Google play store with subscription in-app purchases. I've noticed on the Apple App that people are able to order the subscriptions for less than $1 while the actual cost of purchase is around $40.

The order numbers also seem weird. A normal order number would look like a 10-12 digit number like 9999999999999. But these are like 999999999999999.9999999999

I'm unable to understand where these are coming from. Does anyone have any experience with this?

This is only happening on the Apple app and not the Android app. They both use the same scripts for logging orders to the database. I'm totally baffled by this.

I can manually delete the orders and that will disable the user's upgrade, but that's not a long term solution.